# ArcGIS equivalent of "Update Selection Set"

Tags: arcgis-desktop, mapinfo

In MapInfo's MapBasic window I can perform a mass update of a field in a selection by entering UPDATE SELECTION SET TYPE = "APARTMENT". How do I do that in ArcGIS now that I have a selection?

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like you should use the [**Calculate Field**](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//005s00000029000000) tool or the Field Calculator in the Attribute Table window.

Comment: If what you are calculating is complicated, you can save the expression (or just re-run the tool from the results window) to be imported each time you want to re-calculate your selected features.

Comment: B-E-A-U-T-ful. That is just what I needed. Thanks.